I2C Bus Emulation on STM32 microcontroller
I have a custom board with a STM32 microcontroller as An I2C master which communicating with 3 I2C slave devices. Illustrated in Image 1.


I can simply sniff I2C bus with a logic analyzer to see what are the addresses and registers, so I can write my own implementation.(In fact this is a reverse engineering project, Illustrated  Image 2)


What now I need is to add a new microcontroller to my project to sniff I2C bus, Not as a passive device(i.e. logic analyzer), but like a transceiver or switch (something like what TCA9545A TCA9545A do). Illustrated in Image 3.


My Question:
Is it possible to do this in a simple External Interrupt mode like this?
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
    uint8_t datum;

    if (GPIO_Pin == SCL_IT_Pin) {
        // Clock triggered; bit received
        datum = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SDA_GPIO_Port, SDA_Pin);
    } else if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SCL_GPIO_Port, SCL_Pin)) { // SDA pin necessarily
        // START or STOP condition
        // A for START, B for STOP
        datum = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SDA_IT_GPIO_Port, SDA_IT_Pin) ? 'B' : 'A';
    } else {
        // Nothing interesting here...
        return;
    }

    buffer[bufferPos] = datum; // Store the received bit in the buffer

    bufferPos = (bufferPos + 1) % I2C_BUFFER_SIZE;
    if (bufferPos == bufferStart) printf("ERROR! I2C buffer too small!\r\n"); // Buffer overflow!
}


It is possible. This is called software I2C or bitbang I2c, and there are plenty of libraries and code samples that do so with STM32 MCUs. However, most STM32 MCUs have 2 hardware I2C devices which can operate in both master and slave modes so you might not need to do it in software.

Thanks @AndreyTurkin but my question is a bit more tricky, think about situations like clock stretching of a slave. Or sending ACK or NACK from slave to master.
If I was on a simple serial comminution (i.e. UART), I could easily receive a byte with one UART and transmit it with other UART, and vise versa. But not it is not as simple as UART, isn't it?
